# Auth0 rememberLastLogin for username-password-authenticatication does not work

Tags: authentication, oauth, auth0

rememberLastLogin have been set as "true". Currently  only work when user login using google account or facebook account. Here is my step :

1. Browser is clean

   - login using username and password
   - click logout, it will be redirected to login page --> the rememberLastLogin does not work
2. Login using google account first

   - login using google account
   - click logout, it will show "Last time you signed in using..." (my google account is shown) --> the rememberLastLogin property work
   - login using username and password
   - click logout, it will show Last time you signed in using... (my google account is shown) --> weird behavior.

Is rememberlastLogin property only used for login using social media account? 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not passing `sso: false` when displaying Lock, as this will use the [`/oauth/ro`](https://auth0.com/docs/auth-api#!#post--oauth-ro) endpoint to log in with username/password, which is unable to set a SSO cookie on your Auth0 domain. This cookie is used to display the "last time you signed in with..." message.